# Можно ли хранить дробное число в ресурсах?

Tags: android, java

Что-то сколько ни гуглю, везде речь о том, чтобы хранить целые числа в виде

```
<resources>
<integer name="columns_number">4</integer>
</resources>
```

Но что если мне нужно хранить что-то вроде:

```
<resources>
<float name="menu_layout_weight">0.17</float>
</resources>
```

Можно ли хранить вещественные числа?

Comment: Да, я по сути всегда помечаю же, просто не всегда сразу (сперва проверяешь ответ, а потом только как в следующий раз по сути зашел на хэшкод). Но благодарность и признание рано или поздно находит своего героя=)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, можно. Почитайте [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282390/add-floating-point-value-to-android-resources-values).

**Обновление**

В ресурсах хранятся константы разных типов. С ним проще работать, если, к примеру, ширина виджета везде должна быть 4dp. Разработчик прописывает ссылку на этот ресурс. Через время нужно менять дизайн и вместо 4dp нужно поставить 2dp. Разработчик меняет в ресурсах значение и все, по xml фалам "бегать" ему не нужно. удобно выходит))

Comment: Если число не нужно локализовать, то проще (ИМХО)хранить его в каком-то классе с константами, а не в ресурсах...

Comment: @metalurgus, Обновил ответ

Comment: Я даже больше скажу, для разных экранов разные числа храню, чтобы отдельно настроить =)

Comment: @Saint, хорошая мысль у Вас! =)

Answer (score 1):

```
<resources>
<item name="menu_layout_weight" format="float" type="dimen">.17</item>
</resources>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282390/add-floating-point-value-to-android-resources-values

Comment: для справки: *свой* ответ/вопрос можно не только удалять (на самом деле он и не удаляется, а становится [недоступным для просмотра пользователям с репутацией ниже 2000 баллов](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)), но и вносить в него правки с помощью ссылки [edit].